# Template Argument syntax as an expression

Tags: c++, templates, object, expression, sfinae

Does anyone know how the following code works for the template argument for enable_if?

```
template <int n> void f(typename std::enable_if<(n < 0)>::type* = 0) {
/* ... n is negative ... */
}
template <int n> void f(typename std::enable_if<(n >= 0)>::type* = 0) {
/* ... n is positive ... */
}
```

Specifically this part `(n < 0)>::type*` which doesn't make sense to me because this looks like the compiler is implicitly converting the expression `(n < 0)` into an object.

I have also seen this style of treating an expression as an object in a few other SFINAE examples but what is happening here is eluding me. Is the object defined in some c++ header or is this already in the standard? If so what is this technique of treating an expression as an object called and how can I read up more about this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this looks like the compiler is implicitly converting the expression (n < 0) into an object

No. `n < 0` is the template argument (with type `bool`) of [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), and `std::enable_if<(n < 0)>::type` is a member `typedef` defined inside `std::enable_if` (only exists when `n < 0` is true).

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
struct enable_if;
```

> If `B` is `true`, `std::enable_if` has a public member typedef type, equal
>   to `T`; otherwise, there is no member typedef.
>
> This metafunction is a convenient way to leverage [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to
>   conditionally remove functions from overload resolution based on type
>   traits and to provide separate function overloads and specializations
>   for different type traits. `std::enable_if` can be used as an additional
>   function argument (not applicable to operator overloads), as a return
>   type (not applicable to constructors and destructors), or as a class
>   template or function template parameter.